# Oracle select grant on table which already has all grants

Tags: sql, select, oracle11g, sql-grant

I have table table1 and I want to grant SELECT to table1 to user user1.

I will use below query to grant SELECT.

`grant select on table1 to user1;`

But on production I don't know what all grant user1 has on table1.So What will happen if user1 already has SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, REFERENCES, ALTER and INDEX grant on table1 and execute only SELECT grant.

Comment: Just what you might expect, the `SELECT` grant will be added to any existing grants.

Comment: "If you grant a privilege to a user, then the database adds the privilege to the user's privilege domain."  -- see the following documentation for your version of the database (this one is 10g, but still applicable): https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_9013.htm

Answer (score 0):

The `SELECT` grant will be added, if it doesn't currently exist, to any existing grants for that user.

"If you grant a privilege to a user, then the database adds the privilege to the user's privilege domain."

See the following documentation for your version of the database (this one is 10g, but still applicable):

[Applicable Oracle 10g documentation on grants](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_9013.htm)

Answer (score 0):

> What will happen if user1 already has **SELECT**, INSERT, (...) grant on table1 and execute only **SELECT** grant.

Nothing will happen.

- `GRANT` doesn't work as a switch (i.e. turns a privilege on - another `GRANT` turns it off - yet another turns it on ... - nope).

  - if you want to revoke a privilege, you'd do exactly that: `REVOKE SELECT ON some_table FROM my_user;`
- will it be "double-granted" (so that you'd have to revoke it twice?) - nope, it won't

Therefore, if user is already granted `SELECT` privilege on that table, another grant is useless, but won't do any harm.